# Simulating MouseEvent on Anchor tag has no effect on href in Firefox

Tags: firefox, click, mouseevent, anchor

It works perfectly fine in Chrome as it opens a new tab on meta key press and click. Please see code at

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/1215/).

```
 function simulateClick() {
   var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true,
    'metaKey': true
  });
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
  var canceled = !a.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Second, the metaKey (Mac OS) press has no effect in Firefox. The button click displays alert irrespective of meta key press (Mac OS).

Comment: Any help is appreciated.